# What can I use instead of 'None' so it'll be iterable?

Tags: python, return-type, nonetype, iterable-unpacking

Is there something I can return instead of 'None' so that it's still iterable but empty?
Sometimes I want to return two values but sometimes I only want to return one.

```
for distance in range(1, 8):

    temp_cords = [(origin[0] - ((origin[0]-check[0])*distance)), (origin[1] - ((origin[1]-check[1])*distance))]

    if temp_cords in all_locations:
        return False, None #I want to return only 'False' here.

    elif temp_cords in (white_locations + black_locations):

        if white_turn:

            if temp_cords in white_locations:
                return True, (distance - 1) #But here, I want to return two values.
```

Comment: What about `[]`?

Comment: @Chris I think they want (whatever is returned) to be an iterable, seeing as `distance - 1` isn't an iterable in the second example

Comment: It doesn't make much sense, because (distance -1) is not iterable either.

Comment: What about `return True, ((distance - 1), )`

Comment: How do you use what you return? If this code is in a function `foo()` you're doing `bar, baz = foo()`, then you can just return `None`. Why do you need `baz` to be an iterable? `distance-1` isn't an iterable in the other case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is never a good design to create a function that returns a tuple whose length can vary based on different conditions because the caller would not be able to simply unpack the returning tuple into a fixed number of variables.

In your case, it is better to not return a Boolean but simply `return distance - 1` by default, and then either:

- `return None` when `temp_cords in all_locations` is `True`, so that caller can just check whether if the returning value is `None` to decide what to do with the returning value
- or, raise an exception so that the caller can call the function in a `try-except` block to handle the condition when `temp_cords in all_locations` is `True`.

Comment: Even inhomogeneous/optional return type with `None` is a bit sketchy.  I'd often prefer to always return an integer, otherwise raise an exception.

Comment: `None` can be useful as a default returning value sometimes when you are sure that the regular returning values of the function can never be `None`, as in the case of the standard `dict.get` method. But I agree that in general an exception handler is the way to go.